# Using showkeys and cleveref together

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, showkeys

I'd like to use `showkeys` to show me the labels of my definitions (this works) and the labels of the used references (this does not work). The reason for the latter problem is that I use the `cleveref` package, i.e. `\Cref{thm:something}` instead of `\ref{thm:something}`. Changing all `\Cref` to `\ref` helps, but I'd like to stick to `\Cref`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[]{showkeys}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\label{cha:A}
\chapter{B}
In \Cref{cha:A} something was done.
In \ref{cha:A} something was done.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`showkeys` defines `\SK@def` to hook itself on to other commands, I think you want

```
\makeatletter
  \SK@def\Cref#1{\SK@\SK@@ref{#1}\SK@Cref{#1}}%
\makeatother
```

in the preamble after loading both packages.

[image]

Comment: Seems not to work for `\cref{A,B}`

Comment: @user4514 I just tried the analogous definition for cref and it worked for me: `\SK@def\cref#1{\SK@\SK@@ref{#1}\SK@cref{#1}}%`