# Why cleveref changes show keys in equations and theorems environments?

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, labels, cleveref, showkeys

I think my question is not very clear, the reason is that I am not sure which package gives the problem:

When I label an equation as \label{eq:abc}, on the right of the equation I obtain:

{eq:abc} ---  If "cleveref" is loaded;

eq:abc   ---  If "cleveref" is not loaded;

I would like to delete open and close curl bracket from the label.

I will show the issue

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{abc}
2=2
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Cleveref is Loaded]

What I would like is to have only eq:abc, instead of {eq:abc}.
This issue happens only in equations environment, and not in theorems environment.
Moreover, when I use \cref{eq:abc}, the brackets don't appear.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your MWE (Minimal Working Example, the code you posted) is missing a `\documentclass`, but for all the ones I tried, the output looks just fine (i.e. a boxed `abc` next to the equation tag, and the same `abc` when I reference it with `\ref` (different appearance, of course, but no bracketts)). Regarding `\cref`: the `showkeys` [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/showkeys.pdf) doesn't redefine `\cref`, so I'm guessing some manual adjustments need to be made.

Comment: why does it matter? showkeys is just a rough debugging aid to see what labels have been used given that it was written decades before cref it seems good that it does anything sensible at all.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139701/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for your comments. I would like to understand how to modify that part of the code, actually I am using
\makeatletter
 \SK@def\Cref#1{\SK@\SK@@ref{#1}\SK@Cref{#1}} 
 \SK@def\cref#1{\SK@\SK@@ref{#1}\SK@cref{#1}}
\makeatother
which doesn't do what I would like.